# Can someone help me find what is wrong with my code?

Tags: discord, discord.js, stopwatch

Im trying to make a stopwatch command that when you say !duty on and then !duty off it will calculate the time took to stop it. It works like a regular stopwatch but it is for discord. I have been trying to fix the err for a week but i cant understand why it doesnt work pls help me. The err is in line 10 `id` where it says `message.guild.id`

the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const StopWatch = require("timer-stopwatch-dev"); 
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = {
    name: 'duty',
    description: "This is a stopwatch command",
    async execute(client, message, args, CurrentTimers) {
      try {
          let guildTimers = CurrentTimers.get(message.guild.id);
          let guildTimersUser = guildTimers.get(message.author.id);
          if(!guildTimersUser){ guildTimers.set(message.author.id, new StopWatch()); guildTimersUser = guildTimers.get(message.author.id); };

 if(!args[0] || args[0] === 'on'){
   if(guildTimersUser.isRunning()) return message.channel.send('You need to stop your shift first!')
   guildTimersUser.start();
   message.channel.send('You have started your shift')
 } else if(args[0] === 'off'){
  if(!guildTimersUser.isRunning()) return message.channel.send('You need to start the Stopwatch first!')
  guildTimersUser.stop();
  message.channel.send(new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle('You have stopped the Stopwatch!').setDescription('Total Time: ' + dhm(guildTimersUser.ms)).setTimestamp());
 }

 }
 
 catch(err) {
   console.log(err)
 }

 function dhm(ms){
  days = Math.floor(ms / (24*60*60*1000));
  daysms=ms % (24*60*60*1000);
  hours = Math.floor((daysms)/(60*60*1000));
  hoursms=ms % (60*60*1000);
  minutes = Math.floor((hoursms)/(60*1000));
  minutesms=ms % (60*1000);
  sec = Math.floor((minutesms)/(1000));
  return days+" days, "+hours+" hours, "+minutes+" minutes, "+sec+" seconds.";
    }
   }
  }
```

my main:

```
require('dotenv').config();
//create cooldowns map
const cooldowns = new Map();
module.exports = (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = '!';

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || 
                    client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
    
    if(command){

    //If cooldowns map doesn't have a command.name key then create one.
    if(!cooldowns.has(command.name)){
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

    //If time_stamps has a key with the author's id then check the expiration time to send a message to a user.
    if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
        const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

        if(current_time < expiration_time){
            const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;

            return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds before using ${command.name}`);
        }
    }

    //If the author's id is not in time_stamps then add them with the current time.
    time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
    //Delete the user's id once the cooldown is over.
    setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);
    }
    
    try{
        command.execute(message,args, cmd, client, Discord, CurrentTimers);
    } catch (err){
        message.reply("There was an error trying to execute this command!");
        console.log(err);
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Make sure to take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should write a title that summarizes the question.

Comment: Can you show the actual error

Comment: yes `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/New-Wave-RP/commands/duty.js:10:61)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn’t show the actual error but I suspect that it is something like `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. The way to fix this is to make sure of 2 things:

1. Make sure the message is not in DM
2. Make sure your execution parameters are passed in correctly.

```js
command.execute(client, message, args, CurrentTimers)
//these may not be the same variable names, but make sure the values are correct
```

Comment: you mean my main?

Comment: Yes. However you call this file

Comment: No. You can edit it into your question. Also, before editing it in, you may accept my edit suggestion.

Comment: ok ive apploaded it its big for main code i know

Comment: You just leaked your token with that edit! Reset your token as soon as possible.

Comment: I do not see your execution code. Where do you do `command.execute(…)`?

Comment: in my event handler

Comment: Show that instead.

Comment: As I said, the parameters aren’t passed in correctly

Comment: how is that possible i have checked them like a million times. You mean the order?

Comment: Your execute parameters are `(message,args, cmd, client, Discord, CurrentTimers)` instead of what you defined it as  `(client, message, args, CurrentTimers)`

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped!